# Split ping RoundTripTime

Tags: networking, ping, traffic-shaping, icmp

[Data obtained from ping: is it round trip or one way?](https://serverfault.com/questions/438475/data-obtained-from-ping-is-it-round-trip-or-one-way) shows that the data of a ping measures both directions together.

Is there any way to split this information in time-to-destination and time-back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the time measurement happens inside the ping command with a simple time diff calculation between when the ping was sent and when it was received back. There is no timestamp information in the ICMP request that would allow to split this.

Comment: Questions asking for tools are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here. Your question has been answered.

Comment: Read on until you end up with "and is not about ... product, service, or learning material recommendations". This includes tool requests.  What you cite is about *using* tools.